# Android Webviewにてユーザーエージェントを変更後サーバのアクセスログを見ると faviconの読み込むときのユーザーエージェントが変わらない

Tags: android, webview

Android Webviewにてユーザーエージェントを変更&実行後サーバのアクセスログを見ると faviconの読み込むときのユーザーエージェントが変わらない

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); //ブラウザ定義
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
//ユーザーエージェントを書き換えるところ
//String userAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("MyBrowzer777");
---省略--
webView.loadUrl("http://myinfo.info/info.php");
```

上記コードを実行すると

- ./info.phpのアクセス時には MyBrowzer777のユーザエージェント
- ./favicon.icoのアクセス時には端末固有のユーザーエージェント

になってしまいます。

```
192.168.2.114 - - [03/Jan/2019:12:42:54 +0900] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 200 663 "-" "MyBrowzer777"
192.168.2.114 - - [03/Jan/2019:12:42:54 +0900] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5783 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

favicon.icoのアクセス時も　同じユーザーエージェントで読み込むにはどの様な設定が必要か知っておられたらご教授下さい